# TKinter - Unable to update Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to update a `Text` widget, but it's not updated no matter what I try, there is no error as well

```
def update():# a button calls this

    textBox.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    textBox.insert(tk.END,"test")


textBox = tk.Text(frame1,height=2,width=10)
textBox.config(state='disabled') #disable editing

textBox.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=2)
```

Comment: You need to bring the state back to normal before deleting the text.

Comment: How do I do that @JacksonPro

Comment: `textBox.config(state='normal')`

Comment: @JacksonPro that doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: First set tit to normal, then update, then set it back to disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @JacksonPro's suggestion

```py
import tkinter as tk

def update():# a button calls this
    textBox.config(state="normal") # Make the state normal
    textBox.delete("0.0", "end")
    textBox.insert("end", "test")
    textBox.config(state="disabled") # Make the state disabled again


root = tk.Tk()

textBox = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.config(state="disabled") #disable editing
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=update)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but there is no change.. no errors either

Comment: I also removed the line that made it disabled to try updating but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have a button or something that is supposed to call `update`?

Comment: @relime2543 If it still doesn't work in your code, edit your answer with the code that creates the button. I think the problem is that `update` is never called.